# Don't know how to use . and $ operator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I am not sure how to implement the `.` and the `$` operators to simplify the following definitions:

```
compress :: [Char] -> [Char]
compress [] = []
compress as
    | g as 1 == 1 = [head as] ++ compress (drop 1 as)
    | otherwise = [head as] ++ show (g as 1) ++ compress (drop (g as 1) as)

g :: [Char] -> Int -> Int
g [] i = i
g (a:[]) i = i
g (a:as) i
    | a == head as = g as (i + 1)
    | otherwise = i

main = getLine >>= \str -> putStrLn $ compress str
```

I've read that the `.` operator is a functional composition so that the output of one function goes to the input of another, and `$` is a substitute for a parenthesis.

Therefore, I tried changing it to

```
compress :: [Char] -> [Char]
compress [] = []
compress as
    | g as 1 == 1 = [head as] ++ compress . drop 1 as
    | otherwise = [head as] ++ show (g as 1) ++ compress . drop (g as 1) as

g :: [Char] -> Int -> Int
g [] i = i
g (a:[]) i = i
g (a:as) i
    | a == head as = g as (i + 1)
    | otherwise = i

main = getLine >>= \str -> putStrLn $ compress str
```

But I get type errors saying

```
could not match '[Char]' with a0 -> [Char]
```

I am a bit confused on how to use those operators.

Comment: If you don't really understand `(.)` and `($)`, I think you should open a seperate question for that (but look it up first). If you want to have your code reviewed, you could go to the codereview stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see a way of using `($)` and `(.)` in this code.

However, you can simplify your code as this:

```
compress :: [Char] -> [Char]
compress [] = []
compress as@(x:xs)
    | g as 1 == 1 = x : compress xs
    | otherwise = x : show (g as 1) ++ compress (drop (g as 1) as)

g :: [Char] -> Int -> Int
g (a:as) i
    | a == head as = g as (i + 1)
    | otherwise = i
g _ i = i

main = getLine >>= putStrLn . compress
```

For instance, this:

```
[head as] ++ compress (drop 1 as)
```

is the same as this:

```
head as : compress (drop 1 as)
```

And by using pattern matching, it becomes even shorter:

```
x : compress xs
```

The operators you want to use are commonly use to write a shorter version (with less parentheses) of a function. For instance, your `compress` function could be written this way:

```
compress :: [Char] -> [Char]
compress = concatMap (\x -> head x : show (length x)) . group
```

instead of this:

```
compress :: [Char] -> [Char]
compress xs = concat $ map (\x -> head x : show (length x)) $ group xs
```

or even this

```
compress :: [Char] -> [Char]
compress xs = concatMap (\x -> head x : show (length x)) (group xs)
```

Here is a simpler example:

```
capitalizeWords :: String -> String
capitalizeWords string = unwords (map (\(f:rest) -> toUpper f : rest) (words string))

main = putStrLn (capitalizeWords "here you are")
```

can be rewritten to:

```
capitalizeWords :: String -> String
capitalizeWords = unwords . map (\(f:rest) -> toUpper f : rest) . words

main = putStrLn $ capitalizeWords "here you are"
```

Here are the explanations:

The `($)` can be used in the `main` function because this operator can be viewed as wrapping in parentheses what is on the right of it.

For the `capitalizeWords` function, it can first be simplify to this:

```
capitalizeWords string = unwords $ map (\(f:rest) -> toUpper f : rest) (words string)
```

using the previous explanation.

Again, we can use `($)`:

```
capitalizeWords string = unwords $ map (\(f:rest) -> toUpper f : rest) $ words string
```

And as the `string` parameter is on the right of both side of the equality, we can use composition to remove this parameter. So we get the final `capitalizeWords` function shown above.

You can learn more about the `($)` and `(.)` operators [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application).

There are tools that can help you writing point-free functions like [hlint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint) and [pointfree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree).

Comment: Further improvement: delete the first two patterns in `g` and simply use `g _ i = i` as the catch-all pattern.

Comment: No! `g _ i` shoukd be the last pattern ;)

Comment: Minor point: `getLine >>= \str -> putStrLn $ compress str` can be shortened to `getLine >>= putStrLn . compress`